# Is there a shortcut to invert this 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Is there an easy way to invert the matrix on right-hand-side? Like is there some quick formula or observation we can make or do I have to do it manually all the way? Please, dont be harsh on me since I am not good at linear algebra.

[image]

EDIT:
Result

[image]

Comment: Notice that it's an orthogonal matrix, as the columns are orthonormal (mutually orthogonal, and each have length $1$). To invert an orthogonal matrix, simply take the transpose.

Comment: Hmm, this is the rotation matrix, for a rotation of $\phi$ about the z axis. If it is denoted by $R_\phi$, then it's inverse is $R_{- \phi}$.

Comment: Just to add: the above two comments agree since $\sin(-\phi)=-\sin(\phi)$ and $\cos(-\phi)=\cos(\phi)$ for all angles $\phi$.

Comment: It is a block matrix, so you can invert the blocks separately.

Comment: There's something odd about your notation. The vector on the RHS looks like it is in cylindrical coordinates but the rotation matrix applies to cartesian coordinates.

Comment: This is supposed to be a transformation vector from cylindrical to cartesian coordinates if I am right.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos \phi & 0 & 0 \\ \sin \phi & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}r \\ \phi \\ z\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}r \cos \phi \\ r \sin \phi \\ z\end{pmatrix}$ is the transformation from cylindrical to spherical. But everyone writes it the latter way because it would be bizarre to use a matrix containing $\phi$, one of the coordinates to be transformed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally if $A$ is a *block matrix*, that is a matrix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_1 \\ & A_2 \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & A_n \end{pmatrix}$$

for square matrices $A_i$, and zeroes in all the blank spots, and if all the matrices $A_i$ are invertible, then $A$ is also invertible, with inverse

$$\begin{pmatrix} A_1^{-1} \\ & A_2^{-1} \\ & & \ddots \\ & & & A_n^{-1} \end{pmatrix}.$$

You should convince yourself of this with some small examples.  Anyway, do you know how to quickly inverse a $2$ by $2$ matrix?  By the principle I mentioned, you can immediately invert your $3$ by $3$ matrix, which is a block matrix consisting of the $2$ by $2$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \phi & -\sin \phi \\ \sin \phi & \cos \phi \end{pmatrix}$$

and the $1$ by $1$ matrix $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I calculated the inverse and the only thing that changed was that there is now no minus sign in the top sin. It has instead moved to the bottom sin. Does it sound right? I have edited my question with my result.

Comment: @Clone Yes, that is correct. Note that it agrees with what I said in my comment above: that the inverse is just the transpose in this case.

Comment: @TheoBendit, thank you for the clarification!